# Setting `server-id` variable in MySQL doesn't work

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I've been trying to set up two databases as master & slave.

I followed the famous guide here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto-existingdata.html

But no luck on my slave server,
The issue I'm having is setting the `server-id` variable.
No matter where I define it (I looked into all the possible cnf files that might allow me to define the variable)

I tried to define it like so:

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 2
```

I also tried setting it by using SET GLOBAL server_id but obviously, it didn't save the setting.

when I do:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id'
```

It returns

```
server_id 0
```

Among the cnf files I've looked into are:

```
etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
etc/mysql/debian.cnf
etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
usr/my.cnf
usr/my-new.cnf
usr/etc/my.cnf
```

My MySQL server is running on Ubuntu.
And if it matters, I start it by typing:

```
service mysql start
```

I'd love to know where else I could look to fix this issue.
Thanks a bunch!

Additional Notes:

**MySQL Ignoring the global conf file**

I received this warning a couple of times and it disappeared when I returned the chmod to 644 on the etc/mysql folder, although every thing stated above was attempted using both 644 and 777 permissions, with 644 the warning disappears.

Comment: Dont know much about linx but try restart instead of start in the command line

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for the response but I do use restart, as well as stop, just for some reason it seems like my setting is being ignored.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's to late, but for those who will make the mistake.
It's **server_id** and not **server-id**:

```
[mysqld]
server_id = 2
```

Comment: It's not always `server_id`. Sometimes it's `server-id` and sometimes it's `server_id`. Not sure exactly what it depends on. This answer can be misguiding for some.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by renaming the from /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf to /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.ini

I'm not sure of the exact reason for that (feel free to edit this answer and add to it).

I tried out various combinations:

1. Keeping the variable as: `server-id` and `server_id`
2. Keeping the group/section as: `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]`
3. Renaming the file to: `my.cnf` , `mysqld.cnf`, `mysql.cnf`, `my.ini`

You can keep trying various combinations out of the above options, it should definitely work. :)

Answer (score 0):

`server-id` and `server_id` are actually the same when you use in conf file.

Refercene: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/program-variables.html

Adding those

```
[mysqld]
server_id = 2
```

to mysqld (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld.html) config file locate at `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

**Then restart mysql service**

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

**Check variable**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "server_id";
```