# Difference between server-id and server_id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Running`show variables like 'server%'` shows `server_id` as variable name.

But in `my.cnf`, there's an entry for `server-id` (although commented out)

Is there any differece between the them?

Comment: `-` and `_` in the config file are mapped into `_` when looking at the `VARIABLES`.  That is, they are equivalent.

Comment: @RickJames Does that apply to all variables on both MySQL and MariaDB?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it applies to all variables in both products.  I have seen lots of examples of `-` in use in my.cnf, yet never a verifiable case of failure to map to `_`.  There _may_ be a sentence buried in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are same but as it is stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328652/setting-server-id-variable-in-mysql-doesnt-work), if your server-id is not changed by setting `my.cfg` you can try setting it by underscore

```
[mysqld]
server_id = 2
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18, with a percona 5.7.32-35-log version, I actually discovered that server_id does not force a new UUID value if you delete the aut.cnf, but if you use server-id and do the same the UUID does change.  Hope this is helpful for those doing binary slave copies.

Answer (score 3):

**MySQL**

[4.2.9 Using Options to Set Program Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/program-variables.html):

> ...
>
> If you like, underscores in a variable name can be specified as
>   dashes. The following option groups are equivalent. Both set the size
>   of the server's key buffer to 512MB:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> key_buffer_size=512M
>
> [mysqld]
> key-buffer-size=512M
> ```
>
> ...

**MariaDB**

[Server System Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/) and [mysqld Options](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld-options/):

> ...
>
> By convention, server variables have usually been specified with an
>   underscore in the configuration files, and a dash on the command line.
>   You can however specify underscores as dashes - they are
>   interchangeable.
>
> ...

**Test MySQL**

File: `my.cnf`

```bsh
[mysqld]
. 
.
.
server_id=987
.
.
.
```

Command-Line:

```bsh
$ mysql --execute="SELECT VERSION(), @@server_id"
+-----------+-------------+
| VERSION() | @@server_id |
+-----------+-------------+
| 8.0.13    |         987 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

File: `my.cnf`

```bsh
[mysqld]
.
.
.
server-id=321
.
.
.
```

Command-Line:

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql

$ mysql --execute="SELECT VERSION(), @@server_id"
+-----------+-------------+
| VERSION() | @@server_id |
+-----------+-------------+
| 8.0.13    |         321 |
+-----------+-------------+
```